# ASP.Net-MVC page with JQuery Tablesorter, only passed back 1 page of data back to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using C# ASP.Net MVC with a page that uses the [JQuery Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/).  I have data displayed in the table with a Checkbox on each row for the user to select.

The problem is if I select a row on the first page & another on the 2nd page, it doesn't send all the rows to the controller - only the ones currently shown. I would expect it to send all rows but with the ones where I have ticked it have a CheckSelected set to true.

I have most of my models columns set with hidden fields as I don't need to display them, like so:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[count].DraftId)
```

and the check box column listed inside a TD like this:

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model[count].CheckSelected)
```

The columns I want to display are in a TD like this:

```
 @item.FileName
```

- If I take the tablesorter pager plugin off the table, so it's one massive table it works.
- Comparing the non-pager vs pager HTML it's identical
- The tablesorter jquery is removing all elements from the DOM (I can see this in Firebug) - hence why I'm not getting all results.

Is there anyway round this or is this an inherent bug/design feature of Tablesorter?

Cheers,

Pete

Answer (score 0):

great question!

JQGrid just does not do that - remember the selections on a previous page that is. What you need to do is:

1) Create a hidden field

2) When you tick/untick a selection, update the hidden field with the key of the column in a comma separated list or something...

3) Pass pack the list of keys to the controller to do your processing with.

Should do what you need to get you going.
Cheers,
Pete